# База данных, проблема с ключевыми полями

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Проблема с таблицей "Изделия". Проблема в том что там должны быть повторения индексов. Но беда в том что поле ключевое. Естественно повторы не допускаются, но по сути это поле должно быть ключевым, ибо у него есть зависимости. 
Нужно ли вводить доп.сущность? Хотелось бы без неё решить и так таблиц хватает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что код изделия неуникален?

Comment: Что то я не понял, вы хотите сказать, что там могут повторятся коды изделий, но если у нас два изделия с кодом 'ABC', то как нам понять записи в таблице, например, "состав изделия" ссылаются не первое изделие с кодом 'ABC' или на второе ?

Comment: @defaultlocale locale Как раз-то он и уникален, проблема в том что необходимо будет сделать выборку: Например количество выпущенных единиц какого-то конкретного вида за месяц, а если в таблице всего одна уникальная запись, то с выбрки толку нет

Comment: а может Вы что то делаете не так? напрашивается дополнительная таблица которая будет для продукции, в этом случае в **справочнике** изделия будут уникальные значения а в продукции будет то что Вам надо. ну это так решение в лоб

Comment: @Mike, код уникален, состав изделия ссылается только на одно изделие

Comment: Проблема не ясна. В какой таблице повторяются какие поля? По какой таблице делаете выборку и что смущает?

Comment: @defaultlocale проблема у тс насколько я смог понять в том что ему нужно учитывать *реализованную* продукцию а в текущей приведенной схеме это не представляется возможным. imho

Comment: *Хотелось бы без неё решить и так таблиц хватает* если есть возможность то стоит добавить новую таблицу -таблиц должно быть ровно столько сколько нужно для решения задачи

Comment: @Bald возможно и так, но хорошо бы текст вопроса уточнить. Реализованную продукцию учитывать можно, т.к. в составе заказа код изделия висит

Comment: @defaultlocale кстати вариант, единственно напрашивается поле информирующее о состоянии заказа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется нужно вводить дополнительную сущность, если вы хотите использовать Код_Изделия в качестве первичного ключа.

Альтернативой может быть создание составного первичного ключа, но на мой взгляд, это не правильно, исходя из вашего последнего комментария.

Лучше все таки создать отдельную сущность, которая будет хранить в себе савокупность Кода изделия и Даты изготовления. Тогда при необходимости вы всегда сможете собрать статистику.

P.S

1)По правилам хорошего тона, название полей и сущностей лучше использовать английские

2)"Таблиц итак много"... Много таблиц не бывает. 7 таблиц это еще мало, у меня было и 20 таблиц.

Comment: Опять же, если в таблице будут код и дата то тогда опять будет ключ на одном из полей, чисто логически даты могут совпадать а если поставить ключевое поле, то все

Comment: @Abraham ключевое поле *может* состоят из нескольких полей таблицы - это называется комплексный(составной) ключ